# Function doesn't remove punctuations

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm  new with python and I'm having problems with my function. I need to remove punctuation symbols from the string, so, the simplest thing I could think up is to loop the string and replace the punctuation for an empty character; though the function actually does remove full stops, it doesn't do it with the comma. I tried to debug it and it recognises the comma in the condition, but it doesn't remove it.

The code is this:

```
string = "the Zen of Python, by Tim Peters. beautiful is better than ugly. explicit is better than implicit. simple is better than complex."


def remove_punctuation(string):

    punctuation = [",", "."]

    for char in string:
        if char in punctuation:
            raw_string = string.replace(char, "")

    return raw_string

print(remove_punctuation(string))
```

The thing is the exercise says I can only use replace or del, so I'm a bit restricted with this.

Comment: Can you use regex ?

Comment: why not simply do `string.replace(",", "").replace(".", "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### solution number 1:

with replacing:

```py
def remove_punctuation(string):
    punctuation = [",", "."]

    for char in punctuation:
        string = string.replace(char, "")

    return string


string = "the Zen of Python, by Tim Peters. beautiful is better than ugly." \
         " explicit is better than implicit. simple is better than complex."

print(remove_punctuation(string))
```

basically we do the replacing one per each character in `punctuation`.

##### solution number 2:

If you wanna get better performance you can `.translate` the string:

```py
def remove_punctuation(string):
    punctuation = [",", "."]
    table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(punctuation))
    return string.translate(table)
```

In translation, each key that has the value of `None` in the table, will be removed from the string. `fromkeys` will create a dictionary from an iterable and put `None` as their values (it's the default value)

Comment: Thanks a lot, my main error was create another variable instead of using "string" argument in the return. Thanks again.

Comment: @ilos28 Yes you had to assign the result of replacing operation to the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to use regex and its magic to strip away the special characters:

```py
import re

foo = "I'm a dirty string...$@@1##@*((#*@"

clean_foo = re.sub('\W+','', foo )

print(clean_foo) # Does not remove spaces (Outputs Imadirtystring1)

clean_foo2 = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', foo)

print(clean_foo2) # Remove special chars only :D (Outputs IIm a dirty string1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep on replacing the punctuation once, and then replace again on the original instead of the modified string.

Try this:

```
def remove_punctuation(string):

    punctuation = [",", "."]

    for punc in punctuation:
        string = string.replace(punc, "")

    return string

print(remove_punctuation(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have 2 loops, the inner loop replaces first the comma using string, and for the dot it is using the same unmodified value of `string` again.

So the string is 2 times used as the source, and the replacement of the second iteration replacing the dot is only stored in `raw_string` giving you the result with only the dots removed.

You might use a single call using a character class matching either `.` or `,` with re.sub

```
import re

string = "the Zen of Python, by Tim Peters. beautiful is better than ugly. explicit is better than implicit. simple is better than complex."

def remove_punctuation(string):
    return re.sub(r"[,.]", "", string)

print(remove_punctuation(string))
```

Output

```
the Zen of Python by Tim Peters beautiful is better than ugly explicit is better than implicit simple is better than complex
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use import punctuations which is a list with all punctuations. Then add each character in the sentence to `raw_string` if it isn't in `punctuation`.

```
from string import punctuation

sentence = "the Zen of Python, by Tim Peters. beautiful is better than ugly. explicit is better than implicit. simple is better than complex."


def remove_punctuation(string):
    raw_string = ""
    for char in string:
        if char not in punctuation:
            raw_string += char

    return raw_string

print(remove_punctuation(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have the shortest and fastest answer, you can just remove everything with a translation table like so:

```
>>> import string
>>> s = "the Zen of Python, by Tim Peters. beautiful is better than ugly. explicit is better than implicit. simple is better than complex."
>>> s.translate(str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))
'the Zen of Python by Tim Peters beautiful is better than ugly explicit is better than implicit simple is better than complex'
```

Answer (score -1):

You redefine `raw_string` at every iteration from scratch, so you only see the effect of the last iteration. You need to 'accumulate' the modifications:

```
def remove_punctuation(string):

    raw_string = string 
    
    punctuation = [",", "."]

    for char in string:
        if char in punctuation:
            raw_string = raw_string.replace(char, "")

    return raw_string
```

You can also do this using 'list' comprehension:

```
"".join(c for c in string if c not in punctuation)
```